# Where are GNU coreutils binaries located after building with make?

Tags: build, gnu-coreutils, fuzzing, afl-fuzz

I want to practice fuzzing on the [GNU coreutils](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git) with [AFL](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/afl/). My plan is to compile coreutils binaries with the afl-gcc to be able to run AFL on them.

I have been able to successfully compile the coreutils with AFL's compiler by running `./configure CC="afl-gcc" CXX="afl-g++" --disable-shared; make`

However, I don't understand where the binaries from running `make` are located after the compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the binaries can be located in the `src` folder after compilation.